# How to set variable in python django template from a function call?

Tags: python, django

I have the following library which returns a dict:

```
{% load path_parts %}
```

I can successfully call the method and print the value:

```
{% path_parts request.get_full_path %}
```

I would like to assign the dict to a variable, but I cannot:

```
{% with paths=path_parts request.get_full_path %}
```

How can I assign a result of a function call to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You must try this instead :

```
{% with path_parts request.get_full_path as paths %}
    <!-- use paths here -->
{% endwith %}
```